# Search query in XML datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement that i want to search for data in xml data type, from the front end i will get firstname,lastname,dob,email all the fields are not mandatory some fields will come as empty or null i want to search according to that if i will get firstname as 'test' and lastname i will get as empty or null

If it is a varchar datatype then i can create query as

```
FirstName= ISNULL(@firstname, FirstName) or COALESCE(@firstname, FirstName, '') = '')
```

but in XML doc how can i use this type of query.

```
xmlDoc.value('(/personalDetails/firstname)[1]','varchar(100)')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer 2008, I would write something like :

```
select 
    xmlDoc.value('(personalDetails/firstname/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as firstname 
from 
    myTable 
where 
    not xmlDoc is null
    and xmlDoc.exist('personalDetails/firstname[.!='''']')>0
```

You can also do a CASE WHEN ... ELSE ... END if you want to return NULL for non existing values

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using common table expression. PFB the sample code-

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML
SET @XMLData ='
<STUDENTS>
  <STUDENT>
    <StudentID>1</StudentID>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Marks>200</Marks>
  </STUDENT>
  <STUDENT>
    <StudentID>2</StudentID>
    <Name>Mark Johnson</Name>
    <Marks>300</Marks>
  </STUDENT>
<STUDENT>
    <StudentID>3</StudentID>
    <Name></Name>
    <Marks>400</Marks>
  </STUDENT>
</STUDENTS>'
;with cte as(
SELECT StudentID = Node.Data.value('(StudentID)[1]', 'INT')
        , [Name] = Node.Data.value('(Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        , [Marks] = Node.Data.value('(Marks)[1]', 'INT')
FROM    @XMLData.nodes('/STUDENTS/STUDENT') Node(Data)
)
Select * from cte where Name=''
```